# Eclipse SQLite multiple queries with Where clause

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing, sqlite

Hi I am trying to use a Jtextfield box to search values in my sqlite database with a Jtable I created. So far I have code:

```
    textFieldSearchServer = new JTextField();
    textFieldSearchServer.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            try {
                String query = "select * from server where sid = ?";
                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1, textFieldSearchServer.getText());
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();


                servertable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                pst.close();


            } catch (Exception f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

This code only allows me to search 1 column of data and I want to search the entire database. I have tried using 'OR' statement after where and other alternatives but nothing is working. Any suggestions or fixes will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Can you give an example of one of the non-working queries you've tried?

Comment: I have tried "select * from server where sid OR application = ?" and also tried "select * from server where sid = ? OR application = ?" I tried numerous others I can't remember. My question is can I use the OR clause to do what I am trying to achieve or what I have to use another method? If so what would that be? Am I just using the wrong syntax?

Comment: OR should work fine for this using the second syntax you mentioned. I'm not familiar with prepared statements, but you may need to change the query to use `LIKE '%?%'` in place of `= ?` to find partial matches. You may also run into issues with case not matching, and may need to make your search string lowercase and search against, e.g., `LOWER(application)` instead of just `application`.

Comment: Thanks! Those are all helpful too except I had to change LIKE '%?%' to LIKE ? for it to function properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use OR. For each item, you will need to apply another "set."

```
            String query = "select * from server where sid = ? "
             + "OR application = ?";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, textFieldSearchServer.getText());
            pst.setString(2, textFieldSearchServer.getText());
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

I'm not allowed to comment; this is my only option for responding.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is working, but the value you take from textFieldSearchServer.getText() is incorrect. Have you displayed that? It looks like your search runs each time a key is pressed. So, if you typed in "test", it would run four times, with "

Comment: It might help if you told us how you know it isn't working. Do you get an error message? An empty result set? A result set that isn't what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks that works! Funny how something so simple is easily overlooked. That wasn't all the code I had to make it work but rather the important part that I was trying to figure out. Thanks again.